# X11 XGrabPointer, how do I clear all the events before I release the mouse?

Tags: linux, x11, xlib, xgrabpointer

I am able to grab the mouse, but my problem is that the mouse events that happen while the mouse is grabbed are just queued, and happen after I release the mouse.

this is the code I have until now:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    XEvent e;

    Display* dispaly = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window window = XDefaultRootWindow(dispaly);

    unsigned int count = 0;
    XGrabPointer(dispaly, window, true, PointerMotionMask | ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask, GrabModeSync, GrabModeAsync, None, None, CurrentTime);

    while(count < 500000) {
        if (XPending(dispaly))
            XNextEvent(dispaly, &e);

        count++;
        printf("%d\n", count);
    }


    XFlush(dispaly);

    XCloseDisplay(dispaly);

    scanf("%d", &count);

    printf("end\n");

    return 0;
}
```

as you can see, I tried consuming the all the events in numerous ways, like with XPending and XNextEvent, with XFlush, and also with XSync. 
No matter what function I tried, all the mouse events I do while the mouse is grabbed just happen after I close the display.

can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Create window:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main()
{
  Display* disp     = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  Window   root     = XDefaultRootWindow(disp);
  int      scr      = XDefaultScreen(disp);
  GC       context  = XDefaultGC(disp, scr);
  ulong fg          = BlackPixel(disp, scr);  // fg color
  ulong bg          = WhitePixel(disp, scr);  // bg color
  int depth         = 1;
  Window win        = XCreateSimpleWindow(disp, root, 0, 0, 50, 50, depth, fg, bg);

  long events = 
    ExposureMask |
    ButtonPressMask | 
    ButtonReleaseMask | 
    PointerMotionMask;

  XSelectInput(disp, win, events);
  XMapWindow(disp, win);
  XFlush(disp);

  unsigned int masks = PointerMotionMask | ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask;
  XGrabPointer(
    disp, win, true, masks, GrabModeSync, GrabModeAsync, None, None, CurrentTime
  );
```

Catch pointer events:

```
  XEvent event;

  do { 
    XNextEvent(disp, &event);
    switch (event.type) {
      case ButtonPress    :
        printf("pressed  %i\n", event.xbutton.button);
        break;
      case ButtonRelease  :
        printf("released %i\n", event.xbutton.button);
        break;
      case MotionNotify   :
        printf("move x %i y %i\n", event.xmotion.x, event.xmotion.y);
        break;
      default : break;
    }
    usleep(1000);    

  } while (true);

  XCloseDisplay(disp);
  return 0;
}
```

Or if you need to capture all events inside the **root** window, you may use `XQueryPointer` instead of `XNextEvent`:

```
...
Window root_ret;
Window child_ret;
int x_rel, y_rel;
int x_win, y_win;
unsigned int mask;

do {

  XQueryPointer(
    disp, root,
    &root_ret, &child_ret,
    &x_rel, &y_rel, &x_win, &y_win,
    &mask);
  printf("%d %d\n", x_rel, y_rel);
  usleep(1000);
) while (true);
...
```

Information above would be a good start point to yours researches.

Comment: I am trying to capture events on the entire screen. When I change your code to use root instead of window, it doesn't work. Can you help?

Comment: Querying the pointer in an infinite loop like this is a good way to use 100% CPU and turn your machine into an oven. If you want to track pointer events without blocking them the best way to go is the Xinput extension and raw events.

Comment: I see no reason to reduce the response score only due to minor typos. This is not respectful of other people. If you have right answer - let`s see.

Comment: If a context menu is open (typically after a rigth click) XGrabPointer() returns AlreadyGrabbed and I have no idea how recover the possiblitiy of grab the mouse. Can you give me any tip?

Answer (score 1):

If you log out these two lines of code, you can also get mouse events.

```
unsigned int masks = PointerMotionMask | ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask;
XGrabPointer(disp, win, 1, masks, GrabModeSync, GrabModeAsync, None, None, CurrentTime);
```